# Setting the Style property of a WPF Label in code?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, label

In App.xaml, I have the following code:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LabelTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="53" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="130" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="99,71,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value= "Top" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFE75959" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="40" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

This is meant to provide a generic template for my labels.

In the main XAML code, I have the following line of code:

```
<Label Content="Movies" Style="{StaticResource LabelTemplate}" Name="label1" />
```

However, I'd like to initialize the Style property through code. I have tried:

```
label1.Style = new Style("{StaticResource LabelTemplate}");
```

and

```
label1.Style = "{StaticResource LabelTemplate}";
```

Neither solution was valid.

Any help would be appreciated :).

Comment: Is there any reason to do this from UserControl's codebehind? Maybe there are more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Where in code are you trying to get the style? Code behind?

You should write this:

**If you're in code-behind:**

```
Style style = this.FindResource("LabelTemplate") as Style;
label1.Style = style;
```

**If you're somewhere else**

```
Style style = Application.Current.FindResource("LabelTemplate") as Style;
label1.Style = style;
```

**Bottom note:** don't name a `Style` with the keyword `Template`, you'll eventually end up confusing a `Style` and a `Template`, and you shouldn't as those are two different concepts.

Comment: I found using "App".Current.FindResource() instead of "Application".

Comment: I get FindResource not found

Comment: Found a fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17704969/wpf-application-current-resources-vs-findresource

Answer (score 4):

Please check for null style result or you will be sad...
    ...
     if (style != null)
                this.Style = style;

Comment: When it is null, you can weep or man-up and correct the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an old question, but if you are trying W10 UWP app must use resources collection of each object or resources collection of Application object

```
KeyValuePair<object,object> styl = this.Resources
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "MyStyleTemplateName");
if (styl.Value != null)
    Style MyStyle = (Style)styl.Value;
```

Where **MyStyleTemplateName** must be defined as a resource of **this**