# How do you assign the style programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I am trying to set one of my xaml styles to my frame in my page.
It is created in code, and assigned to the layout dynamically.

So I expect that I have to set the style dynamically? since the frame does not exist in xaml.

What I cannot figure out, is how to assign a custom template. Or better yet, in a global manner to any frames that fit a certain category. Tag, or type etc.

Below is my template that im trying to test with. But it does not work. Assume code is missing, so started checking codebehind style setting, but no luck so far.

*App.xaml*

```
<!-- http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation -->
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Frame" x:Key="frame" >
    <DockPanel Margin="7">
        <StackPanel 
            Margin="7"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            DockPanel.Dock="Top"
            >
                <Button 
                Content="Avast! Go back!" 
                Command="{x:Static NavigationCommands.BrowseBack}" 
                IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding CanGoBack}" 
                />
                <Button 
                Content="Forward you dogs!" 
                Command="{x:Static NavigationCommands.BrowseForward}" 
                IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding CanGoForward}" 
                />
            </StackPanel>

            <Border 
            BorderBrush="Green"
            Margin="7"
            BorderThickness="7"
            Padding="7"
            CornerRadius="7"
            Background="White"
            >
            <ContentPresenter />
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

*MyWindow.xaml.cs*

```
 Frame newFrame = new Frame();
 newFrame.Content = content;

 newFrame.Template = ControlTemplate ...?
```

Comment: Check out this other topic, that is very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686917/setting-the-style-property-of-a-wpf-label-in-code

Comment: Why create things dynamically? You're working pretty hard to make things harder for yourself.

Comment: @EdPlunkett To give background, I am using Devexpress controls. DockPanel. Which requires me adding a panel for each page. Each Panel needs its content, but I wish to have navigation. So I am adding a Frame to the panel, and the content to the frame. The pages themselves, have their own xaml and cs. Unfortunately, the devexpress does not style the navigation window, so i need to override it somehow

Comment: I brought a ham sandwich for lunch, but I put the tomatoes and pickle slices in a ziplock bag so the bread won't get soggy. It's a sunny day out. Kind of cold. But about par for this time of year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1:**

1. Create a style without a Key (inplicit) for your type
2. In the style add the ControlTemplate
3. When you add the control (even it from code) it will get the default style you just created

Code Ex with a button that get hist style form the containing window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
               <ControlTemplate>
                   <... Your Template ...>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Create the Button from Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var button = new Button();
        this.Content = button;
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

1. Create a style with a key.
2. In the style add your ControlTemplate
3. Add the style to the App resources.
4. Get The style from Application resouces and set the style (and the template):

Code Ex:

```
var yourStyle = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["Resource_Name"]);

Frame newFrame = new Frame();

newFrame.Style = yourStyle;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have got it working with similar code. To get the `ControlTemplate` then set `newFrame.Template` with it.

Comment: Great, I think that the first option (Option 1) that I suggested is better and cleaner.