# Is it possible to set a Style in code when Style is not defined in app.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have **myWindow.xaml** which defines "MyStyle"-

```
<ResourceDictionary ...>
    <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        //style definitions etc
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

myWindow.xaml only defines the style, there is no instance of it.

I'd like to set another window to also use MyStyle,  i.e.

```
otherWindow.Style = "MyStyle"
```

I cannot change the xaml of otherWindow, only access it from code.
I also cannot move the style definition to app.xaml.

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686917/setting-the-style-property-of-a-wpf-label-in-code),  where the style was defined in app.xaml and it could be done like so-

```
Style style = Application.Current.Resources["myStyle"] as Style;
otherWindow.Style = style;
```

However, since my style is not defined in app.xaml the call above doesn't work (throws notFound exception).

How can I set MyStyle as the style of another window?

Comment: Can't you get the Style from the Resources of MyWindow?

Comment: @Clemens- how would I do that programmatically?

Comment: If you have an instance of MyWindow, by `window.Resources`.

Comment: @Clemens - there's no instance of it,  it only defines a style which is used by other windows in the application

Comment: Well, then you should move the Style declaration from MyWindow.xaml to App.xaml.

Comment: @Clemens sadly that's not an option for me..   thank you for the help though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyStyle` should of course be defined globally in `App.xaml` if you intend to use if from any other window than `myWindow.xaml`.

If you can't move the style for some reason, you need to create an instance `myWindow` for the style to be created. You can then access it from there:

```
myWindow win = new myWindow();
var style = win.Resources["MyStyle"] as Style;
otherWindow.Style = style;
```

Answer (score 0):

While mm8's answer is correct and was very helpful, I'd still like to throw in my 2cents as to how I ended up fixing this:

```
Style style = Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["MyStyle"] as Style;
otherWindow.Style = style;
```

The main change is using the '**MainWindow**' property which held an **instance** of the window containing MyStyle as the resource (thank you mm8).

With that small change 'MyStyle' is now accessable.

Comment: Yes, this also works assuming that myWindow is actually your MainWindow.

Comment: @mm8 - in my case it was- thank you very much for your help!