# Change windows style on click WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change style on click, but simply cant find any way to do it.
Here is styles

```
 <Style x:Key="CustomWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="200"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="46"/>    
        <!--CaptionHeight + ResizeBorderThickness * 2-->
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="7"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkRed"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource WindowTemplate}"/>
    </Style>

    <!--the red style window-->
    <Style x:Key="RedWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="46"/>            
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="white"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkRed"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="7"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource WindowTemplate}"/>
    </Style>
```

I want to change it in MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Style ?? // dont know what to do
        }
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably bind this in my style. For example:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="local:MainWindow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="Button_Click">Click Me, Yo!</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private bool _someProperty;
        public bool SomeProperty
        {
            get { return _someProperty; }
            set
            {
                _someProperty = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SomeProperty = !SomeProperty;
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, you derive the state of your window from some property in your ViewModel, using a converter if needed.

Of course, if you want a direct solution, you could just use FindResource:

```
this.Style = this.FindResource("MyLocalStyleResourceName") as Style;
```

This is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686917/setting-the-style-property-of-a-wpf-label-in-code).