# WPF create combo box programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to create `DatagridComboBoxColumn` from code behind. How can I link it to `ElementStyle` and `EditingElementStyle`?

I'm trying to create this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="*" ElementStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxElementStyle}" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditingElementStyle}" />
```

which creates this:
[image]

from this:

```
private DataGridComboBoxColumn CreateComboValueColumn()
{
    DataGridComboBoxColumn column = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
    column.ElementStyle = ???;
    column.EditingElementStyle = ???;
    return column;
}
```

Which do not display comboBox:

[image]

Style which I'm trying to link:

```
<!-- ComboBox element and editing style -->
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxElementStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ComboItems}"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding Value}" />
    <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Text"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="ID" />
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxEditingElementStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ComboItems}"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedValue" Value="{Binding Value}" />
    <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Text"/>
    <Setter Property="SelectedValuePath" Value="ID" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting the Style property of a WPF Label in code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686917/setting-the-style-property-of-a-wpf-label-in-code)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer it is somehow duplicate, there is however problem with loading comboBox item list

Comment: What do you mean and how is that related to your question? (And how are we supposed to know if you don't include it in your question?)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I agree that my question is not worded in best way and I should probably edit it. Adding styles to ``comboBox`` from .cs file is however no easy task if you want your ``comboBox`` to work as if you added it from .xaml

Comment: It does work the exact same way. There is no *Runtime-XAML* or something like that. Your program doesn't know the difference.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer added screenshots. How can be something like that possible?

Comment: You haven't even explained what *"something like that"* is. You didn't include your style or anything else needed for a [mcve] (Note that every single word in that phrase is important). Unless we can reproduce what you already have, it's hard to tell you what to change or add. This site exists because there are so many things that can go wrong and your/our job as programmers it to find out what by debugging our programs. If a single error always had the same cause, this site would simply be a long list of what to do when *"It doesn't work"*

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer oh please, I did provide minimal, complate and verifiable example. I pointed out where exactly is the problem - it is with linking style. You simply probably do not have a good day and are trying to be rude to internet strangers.

Comment: Really? You think it's **complete**? You are having problems with a style that isn't included and you think it's complete?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Yes, you are right, I forgot to add that. But I'm glad we start to agree on the fact that this is not duplicate to question you linked.

Comment: At least not anymore. You edited the question to include the answer provided by Vishal - which completely changes the question and might be considered a bad move since it makes the current answers obsolete. 

Anyways, without knowing what your data looks like, I'd say your `column` is missing a `Binding` but that might be on purpose, which I still can only guess.

Comment: To clarify the segments of a [mcve] and why they are important:

**Minimal**: The less code you need to reproduce the issue, the higher the chances of finding the error.

**Complete**: The more I have to guess what your code looks like the less helpful my answers might become (because I could guess wrong)

**Verifyable**: I guess we are past this now. You have a problem that is certainly verifyable.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer ok, I do not have nerves to argue with you, I will ask another question

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer is downvoting my questions making you feel good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello try something like this:

```
private DataGridComboBoxColumn CreateComboValueColumn()
{
DataGridComboBoxColumn column = new DataGridComboBoxColumn();
column.ElementStyle = YourWindowName.FindResource("ComboBoxElementStyle") as Style;
column.EditingElementStyle = YourWindowName.FindResource("ComboBoxEditingElementStyle") as Style;
return column;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but my combobox will not bind itemsource properly

Comment: but why..whats the reason??

Comment: Yes, that is very good question which I'm trying to solve. How can my comboBox works with said styles properly, but adding them like this from .cs won't load items.

Comment: well.. i don't get your question properly..can you please show us some of your code so that we can resolve the issue??

Comment: @Kajbo That's completely unrelated. If the style works when you add it directly in XAML, it will work if you add it from code-behind. You have received an answer to your immediate question, not it is up to you to find out what's wrong. I can guarantee you that the code-behind style is **not** the reason it's not working.

Comment: @Kajbo Please accept the answer if it fulfilled your requiremwnt

Comment: @VishalPrajapati I would gladly do that, my comboBox items are however not showing

Comment: @Kajbo can you please show us the code of your backend file on how your are creating the datagrid and it's column in C#...so that figure out the issue..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like`(Style)FindResource("StyleOne")`

Have a look here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/resources-and-code